# How to use dynamic sprite names with createWithSpriteFrameName?

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x

I want to change a sprite image according to some dynamic variable in Cocos2d-x and C++, so I'm, trying something like this but there is an error. What could it be a right way to do it?. Greetings.

```
auto name = String::createWithFormat("x%i.png", _destroyedUnits);
auto combo = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(name);
```

I've seen that createWithSpriteFrameName accept a C++ basic_string, not a Cocos String, so I created like this and the output is "The name is: ??"

```
int _destroyedUnits = 20;
std::string intToString = std::to_string(_destroyedUnits);
std::string name("x" + intToString);
CCLOG("The name is: %s", name);
```

What's the right way to do it? Greetings.

Comment: What's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in cocos2d-x tests, the right way is to use sprintf, you can use it like this:

```
char tmp[30];
sprintf(tmp,"x%i.png", _destroyedUnits);
std::string atlasName = tmp;
auto combo = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(atlasName.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that createWithSpriteFrameName accepts a C++ basic_string, not a Cocos String, so the way is with string and not String class.

```
int _destroyedUnits = 4;
std::string intToString = std::to_string(_destroyedUnits);
std::string name("x" + intToString + ".png");  
auto combo = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(name);
```

Greetings.